# Qual è il significato di "infilzare allo spillo" in questo testo?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Non ha perso il largo accento piemontese, che si sposa benissimo con quello inglese. Sembra anzi che i due linguaggi siano nati per intendersi nel segno di una bonomia ironica, che **infilza allo spillo** le distorsioni del mondo senza farsene immalinconire, senza alimentare complessi di superiorità.

Capisco il significato delle singole parole di questo brano, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "infilzare allo spillo" in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'atto di infilzare con lo spillo normalmente si riferisce a ciò che fanno gli entomologi (e anche gli appassionati, visto che ci sono [siti](http://www.entomologiitaliani.net/public/forum/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=343&t=30984) a riguardo) per fissare gli insetti sui supporti che fanno parte delle teche da esposizione o da collezione.

Nel passaggio da te indicato l'espressione viene usata in senso figurato con il senso di ***ridurre***, ***compattare***, ***classificare*** e, per estensione, ***circoscrivere*** le differenze tra due linguaggi che, nonostante si portino dietro storie, tradizioni e differenze che si riflettono su molteplici aspetti del mondo contemporaneo, si considerano reciprocamente con rispetto.

Inoltre, ho trovato in [Novecento plurale: scrittori e lingua](https://books.google.it/books?id=dCPvNEa7424C&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=infilzare%20con%20lo%20spillo&source=bl&ots=DPHUn7psl0&sig=tNygArBBm1zmT9GDuRUuwR3WbCs&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_0qHdp6HVAhUDvhQKHcbGAZkQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=infilzare%20con%20lo%20spillo&f=false) il seguente passaggio:

> Perciò si eviterà qui di infilzare con lo spillo di una definizione
>   compatta una vicenda narrativa che conta molti decenni e si è sempre
>   mostrata attenta ai mutamenti della società e degli usi
>   linguistico-stilistici che ne derivano.